# VB 2008 Transferring stored values to textbox after initial textbox value is cleared

Tags: vb.net, textbox, inputbox

Self teaching VB beginner here.

I have a data entry section that includes...

2 comboboxes(cbx_TruckType, cbx_DoorNumber)

-------cbx_TruckType having 2 options (Inbound, Outbound)

-------cbx_DoorNumber having 3 options (Door 1, Door 2, Door 3)

2 textboxes (txb_CustomerName, txb_OrderNumber)

-------txb_CustomerName will hold a customer name

-------txb_OrderNumber will hold an order number

and finally...

a button(btn_EnterTruck) that transfers the text from the comboxes and textboxes to the following...

2 Tabs

The 1st tab has

2 buttons(btn_Door1, btn_Door2)

btn_Door1 has 3 corresponding textboxes

-------txb_TruckTypeDoor1, txb_CustomerNameDoor1, txb_OrderNumberDoor1

btn_Door2 has 3 corresponding textboxes

-------txb_TruckTypeDoor2, txb_CustomerNameDoor2, txb_OrderNumberDoor2

The 2nd tab has

1 button(btn_Door3)

btn_Door1 has 3 corresponding textboxes

-------txb_TruckTypeDoor3, txb_CustomerNameDoor3, txb_OrderNumberDoor3

Currently, I have code (that works thanks to another question I had!) that, upon btn_EnterTruck.click, will transfer the text to the corresponding textboxes.

Here's my problem...

I've coded a msgbox to pop-up (when Inbound is selected from the cbx_TruckType) asking if there is an Outbound. If I click "Yes", an inputbox pops-up and asks for an order number. The button then transfers the Inbound information to the textboxes and stores the Outbound order number.

When I click btn_Door1(or 2 or 3), it clears the text from its corresponding textboxes. (Using me.controls)

( I would add code for all of the above, but I figure its a moot point, because it works)

What I want to happen...

I want to have the stored Outbound number to be saved with a reference to which door number it corresponds to. Then upon btn_DoorX click, it will fill that order number into the corresponding textbox. I don't need the text stored/saved when the app is closed.

And I have no idea how to do that.

*After some tooling, I've done the following, but it does not work"

I declared these at the class level.

```
    Dim str_SameTruckPODoor1, str_SameTruckPODoor2, str_SameTruckPODoor3 As String
```

This code is in the btn_EnterTruck event

```
    Dim str_ErrOutDoorName As String = cbx_DoorNumber.Text

    Dim str_OutboundDoorName As String = str_ErrOutDoorName.Replace(" ", "")

    Dim ArrayForPONumbers As Control() = Me.Controls.Find("str_SameTruckPO" & str_OutboundDoorName, True)

    If cbx_TruckType.Text = "Inbound" Then

        Dim OutboundMsg = "Is there an Outbound with this truck information?"

        Dim Title = "Outbound?"

        Dim style = MsgBoxStyle.YesNo Or MsgBoxStyle.DefaultButton2 Or _
            MsgBoxStyle.Question

        Dim response = MsgBox(OutboundMsg, style, Title)

        If response = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then

            Dim NeedPOMessage, NeedPOTitle, defaultValue As String
            Dim PONumberOutbound As String

            ' Set prompt.
            NeedPOMessage = "Enter the PO Number"

            ' Set title.
            NeedPOTitle = "PO# For Outbound"
            defaultValue = "?"   ' Set default value.

            ' Display message, title, and default value.
            PONumberOutbound = InputBox(NeedPOMessage, NeedPOTitle, defaultValue)

            ' If user has clicked Cancel, set myValue to defaultValue 
            If PONumberOutbound Is "" Then PONumberOutbound = defaultValue

            ArrayForPONumbers(0) = PONumberOutbound

        End If

    End If
```

I'm getting an error message on

```
    ArrayForPONumbers(0) = PONumberOutbound ' Cannot convert string to .controls
```

And I have the following code in the btn_Door1 event - it handles btn_Door2, btn_Door3

```
    Dim WhichButton As Button = CType(sender, Button)

    Dim str_ErrDoorName As String = WhichButton.Name

    Dim str_DoorName As String = str_ErrDoorName.Replace("btn_", "")

    Dim str_DoorType As Control() = Me.Controls.Find("txb_" & str_DoorName & "Type", True)

    Dim str_Customer As Control() = Me.Controls.Find("txb_" & str_DoorName & "Customer", True)

    Dim str_OrderNumber As Control() = Me.Controls.Find("txb_" & str_DoorName & "OrderNumber", True)

    Dim SecondArrayForPONumbers As Control() = Me.Controls.Find("str_SameTruckPO" & str_DoorName, True)

    If str_DoorType(0).Text = "Outbound" Then

        str_DoorType(0).Text = ""
        str_Customer(0).Text = ""
        str_OrderNumber(0).Text = ""

    ElseIf SecondArrayForPONumbers(0).Text.Length > 0 Then

        str_DoorType(0).Text = "Outbound"
        str_OrderNumber(0).Text = Me.Controls("str_SameTruckPO" & str_DoorName).Text

    End If
```

Any help is appreciated. If I'm not clear on what I'm asking or haven't given enough details, please let me know.

Edit: Added info based on comment, Added code, Changed Title

Answer (score 0):

How long do you want this data to be stored? IE: longer than the life of the open application? If the application is closed is it alright if the data is lost? If not, you may want to consider writing this data to an external database.

Comment: Great question! As of now, it's ok for the data( held in the variables) to be lost when the app is closed. Eventually, I will have the information from the door text boxes be transferred to an external file( upon the btn_DoorX click)

Comment: You can write the order number to an array or a listbox with a delimiter for the corresponding door. IE: ordernumber::dornumber. Then when the button is clicked you would find the string containing the door number, split the data using your delimiter and return the order number.

Comment: How would one go about doing that?